# how to join two tables in mysql using a common field

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables. ie,

1. db_post
2. db_like

//db_post

```
id  ||  name  ||  username  ||  unique_key  ||  pub

1       Jit        jit11         unkey1         demo
2       Rah        rah11         unkey2         demo1
3       dee        dee11         unkey3         demo2
```

//db_like

```
id  ||  post_id  ||  unique_key

1          2           unkey3
```

My question is, how to mix this two tables according to unique_key field in table db_post.

//output should be like below. (WHERE unique_key='unkey3')

```
id  ||  name  ||  unique_key  ||  pub   ||  post_id

3       dee         unkey3       demo2       {null}
2       Rah         unkey2       demo1        2
1       Jit         unkey1       demo        {null}
```

`id` field from `db_post` and `post_id` field from `db_like` should match.

Comment: post_id shoulb be 2 according to your example.

Comment: @Abhis :- oh sorry, my mistake. Look the edited question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs left join with the joining condition as `db_unique_key = db_like.unique_key and db_like.unique_key='unkey3')`

```
select
p.id,
p.name,
p.unique_key,
p.pub,
l.post_id
from db_post p
left join db_like l on l.unique_key = p.unique_key and l.unique_key = 'unkey3'
order by p.id desc
```

Comment: In that case just change the joining condition to `left join db_like l on l.post_id = p.id and l.unique_key = 'unkey3'`

Comment: `id` field from `db_post` and `post_id` field from `db_like` should match.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `LEFT JOIN` on `unique_key` column like

```
select dp.id, 
       dp.name, 
       dp.unique_key, 
       dp.pub,
       dl.post_id
from db_post dp 
left join db_like dl on dp.unique_key  = dl.unique_key
order by dp.id desc;
```

Comment: same result is repeating.

Comment: @JithinVarghese, per your edit, you need to order by the ID field. See edit in answer if that helps.